# don't get the values from input text

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i have a serious problem with jsf tabview and form

inside my tabview i have to input text and submit button whenever i submit i always have a empty value.

```
        <h:form id="form">

                <p:tab id="tabview" title="Ressources Humaines">
                <p:tabView    activeIndex="#{SelectBean.activeTab}" value="#{SelectBean.types}" var="item"    >
                <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{SelectBean.onTabChange}" update=":form" />
                <p:tab title="#{item}"> 
                <p:tabView  id="tab"  activeIndex="#{SelectBean.other}"   value="#{SelectBean.res}" var="rr">
                <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{SelectBean.onTabChange1}"  />
                <p:tab title="#{rr.nom_ressource}">


                <p:panel rendered ="#{SelectBean.bol}" closable="true"  toggleable="true"   styleClass="outPanel">

             <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true"  />
                <h:outputLabel value="Nom  " />
               <h:inputText value="#{SelectBean.nom}" />
               <br/>
               <h:outputLabel value="Experience " />
               <h:inputText value="#{SelectBean.exp}" />    
               <br/>
               <h:commandButton immediate="true" value="Modifier" action="#{SelectBean.ok}"/>


                </p:panel>


                </p:tab>
                </p:tabView> 
                </p:tab>



            </p:tabView>



            </h:form>
```

the SelectBean.nom and SelecBean.exp are always empty any help please

Comment: If an answer helps you, could you please check the green mark under which one applies most to your question? Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your

`<h:commandButton immediate="true" value="Modifier" action="#{SelectBean.ok}"/>`

The `immediate` attribute action method causes JSF to go directly to the render phase 'of the same view' by calling `facesContext.renderResponse()`, then the components will behave as they do for a validation failure - by displaying the value cached in the component rather than fetching data from the backing bean.

---

Here is a list of possible [solutions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MYFACES/Clear+Input+Components)